# Why The IEEE-754's formula for determining the precision in bits for an extended binary interchange format is so complex?

Tags: ieee-754

For determining the precision in bits, *p*, for an extended binary interchange format with width *k*, the formula *k – round(4×log2(k)) + 13* is used.
What is important about the logarithm and the `round()` function that they are used in this formula? Can't it simply be defined as *k - 20* for example?

Comment: I suspect it was adopted as a reasonable fit to what is useful, not because of any mathematical requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The original standard had only 32- and 64-bit values.  But the committee realized that someday 128 might be implemented.  So there should be a "formula" for that.  At that point, why stop with nice, neat, powers of two?  What about a 24-bit float?  Or 96?  Or 55?